# Cannot get Geolocation script to work

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-analytics

I scripted the following code, but for some reason it does not work please help thanks

```
<script>
    $.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {

    $location =  geoplugin_countryCode();
$location2 = geoplugin_continentCode();        



    if($location == "CA" || $location == "US" || $location2 == "EU" || $location2 == "DE" || $location2 == "FR" || $location2 == "GB") {
    alert($location);
         var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9240923-27']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

    } else {

         var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9240923-27']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
    } 

});



        </script>
```

Comment: How do you mean it does not work? What happens and what did you expect should happen?

Comment: it does not show in google analytics

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish here. You are loading analytics in both the if and else clause? Why not do it after the if-statement instead then? And why are you loading Google Analytics within the success-callback of `getScript`?

Comment: 1 the analytics code will be modified 2. could you please explain: preferable with an example

Comment: I posted an answer to your question, outlining the way I'd write this code. Since I don't know what you want to accomplish with loading Google Analytics within the success-callback, you'll have to explain a bit more what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a proper answer yet, as it is still unclear what the actual problem is, but to explain to OP, I'll post this as an answer.

```
$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {

    $location =  geoplugin_countryCode();
    $location2 = geoplugin_continentCode();        

    if($location == "CA" || $location == "US" || $location2 == "EU" || $location2 == "DE" || $location2 == "FR" || $location2 == "GB") {
       alert($location);
    }
});

/* 
 * I'm not sure what you want to accomplish 
 * with loading Google Analytics within the success 
 * callback of getScript, so I moved it out here until that is clarified.
 */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9240923-27']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```