# JavaScript: analytics code not loading

Tags: javascript

Could someone please tell me why the analytics code does not load? For US visitors, the alert is being displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {
    $location =  geoplugin_countryName();

    if($location == "Canada" || $location == "United States") {
      alert("12");

    } else {

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9240923-27']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();          
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: under what conditions does it not appear?  You need to provide us with more information.

Comment: Remove '`} else {`' part

Comment: What is the value of $location (which is a weird variable indication in the first place for a JS variable)? Probably 'Canada' or 'United states'. There....problem solved!

Comment: Yea I don't understand either. You want analytics to work for US visitor or not?

Comment: Missing `var` before `$location` assignment.

Comment: @florent, thats definitely not the problem here...

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO here the script works: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/WktTV/ but the analytics code not

Comment: This question looks remarkably similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447839/cannot-get-geolocation-script-to-work/11448304#11448304), from earlier today by another user. Coincident?

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson No me and my friend are working on our site and are both investigating this problem

Comment: have a look at investmoney.me I tried the suggestions on this site and it should show some sort of alert if working have a look at it and then at the sourcecode - thanks for your answer

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0afabzk8e

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be wanting to change accounts based on location, the following code should be what you want:

```
$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {
    var $location =  geoplugin_countryName();
    var account = "";

    if($location == "Canada" || $location == "United States")
        account = 'UA-9240923-27'
    else
        account = "otherAccount";

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', account]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
});
```

**Edit**

You have an illegal character at the end of your javascript. This is what it looks like at the end of your script when I view source:

```
});â€‹
```

You are also missing the `type="text/javascript` on your first script tag, and you should properly format your html file with doctype, html, head, and body.

Comment: No I dont I need the else statement I will use two different analytics codes with diferent variables for the us and the rest

Comment: view-source:http://investmoney.me/

Comment: What exactly is not working. 'It does not work' is extremely vague? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: thats why I supplied this link: investmoney.me I tried it on this site and it should show some sort of alert if working have a look at it and then at the sourcecode - thanks for your answer

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0afabzk8e

Comment: no they cannot this is the cpanel sourecode editor

Comment: Are you saying that the editor wont allow you to delete the extra characters?

Comment: I did it has nothing to do with cpanel I cecked it through transmission - at first I thought it had something to do with jquery missing but that is not the problem - this is so wird and anoying

Comment: How does the character get there. If you cannot remove it in the editor, can you not edit the file directly on the server to see what the issue is?

Comment: I checked the file directly on the server does not have the character in place - to me it looks like an encoding problem but there is non - damm it

Comment: it already looks like that belive me I double checked

Comment: good idea but did not help have a look: http://www.iwebtool.com/code_viewer?domain=investmoney.me

Comment: I know but It is not in the actual source file u know what I give up just dont understand it

Comment: Some of these should be edits on the question. Anything you want to keep, please put on as an edit on the question or the answer.

Comment: @George Stocker I have moved all update suggestions into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want analytics to work for Canada and US only, just remove the  `} else {` statement, as mentionned in comments

Edit: ok then:

```
$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {
    $location =  geoplugin_countryName();

    if($location == "Canada" || $location == "United States") {
    // HERE INSERT THE CODE FOR LOADING ANALYTICS FOR USA
    } else {
        // HERE INSERT THE CODE FOR LOADING ANALYTICS FOR OTHER COUNTRY
      }          
    });
```

Comment: No I dont I need the else statement I will use two different analytics codes with diferent variables for the us and the rest

Comment: Post edited. I really don't understand what's the hard part of it... Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: no does not work see this: http://investmoney.me/

Comment: Well you mistyped at the end, look: http://www.noelshack.com/2012-28-1342105724-Capturedcran2012-07-1217.08.15.png

Comment: no typed: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0afabzk8e

Comment: Well then its the the copy paste that went wrong, cause there's a weird caracter at the end, prolly due to mixed caracter encoding

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this snippet on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wDzBc/

```
$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {
    var location =  geoplugin_countryName();

    if(location == "Canada" || location == "United States") {
      alert("12");
    } else {
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9240923-27']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        alert('ga');
      })();          
    }
});
```

Comment: no sorry does not work http://investmoney.me/

Comment: illegal character
[Break On This Error]  

});â€‹

investmoney.me (line 27, col 4)

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0afabzk8e

Comment: no idea sorry..never used the cpanel editor. just check all your line-breaks...

Comment: I did it has nothing to do with cpanel I cecked it through transmission - at first I thought it had something to do with jquery missing but that is not the problem - this is so wird and anoying